# How to preserve newlines with cat command

Tags: bash, shell, cat, heredoc

I have this:

```
echo `cat << 'EOF'
    select c1, c2 from foo
    where c1='something'
EOF`
```

it logs this to stdout:

> select c1, c2 from foo where c1='something'

but I am looking to preserve newlines somehow, so it outputs:

> ```
> select c1, c2 from foo  
> where c1='something'
> ```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you use ``echo `...` `` instead of just running `cat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes with `echo` to preserve the original format of the string.

```
echo "`cat << 'EOF'
    select c1, c2 from foo
    where c1='something'
EOF`"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `echo` at all:

```
cat <<'EOF'
select c1, c2 from foo
where c1='something'
EOF
```

Comment: that's not the point of the question though, I think @PS. has the right idea

Comment: "How can I [preserve newlines]?" This does that. Do you have a good *reason* for the extraneous `echo`?

Comment: here is the reason: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518928/create-single-string-argument-using-heredoc-or-other-technique

Comment: You don't even need `cat` for that; just use a regular string with embedded newlines.

Comment: ok that sounds good, can you add an answer to the other question then?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of IFS (internal field separator)

This will work

```
Old="$IFS"
IFS=""
My_Var=$(cat ...)
echo $My_Var
IFS="$Old"
```